# How to increase padding in grid in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, grid

I have to do a collectionView with image, two texts and two buttons. I'd like to increase padding of VStack inside LazyVGrid but couldn't achieve it. Could you please help me to figure out what's wrong?

[image]

```
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20, alignment: .center), count: 2)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20, content:  {
                  ForEach(data, id:\.self) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Image("\(item.image)")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
                                    .padding(4)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                        
                            Text(item.name)
                            Text(item.price)
                                    
                        HStack(spacing: 15) {
                                Button(action: {}) {
                                    HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "cart")
                                    Text("В Корзину")
                                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                                }
                                .padding(10)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                Image(systemName: "heart")
                            }
                                .padding(10)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                }       .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                        .padding(15)
            }
                }).padding(15)
                }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a bunch of issues here, and they were each little things that added up to you having significant issues with your view. The first thing I did was change your `column` to `.fixed()`. This may or may not be what you wanted, but it seemed like you wanted equal sized grid items.

I also got the images under control by setting `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` and a `.frame(height: 140)` on them.

Next, I removed as many `.padding()` as I could. I also put more of `VStacks` and `HStacks` in to keep things in logical order. By the time I was done this, it seemed that the issue was the two buttons on the bottom in the `HStack`. There simply wasn't room, so I moved the `favorite` button.

My overall advice. Set frames, but only one direction if possible. Think in logical groupings. Make sure different views fit. Manage your images with a frame and aspect ratios.

I had to make a data struct, and use SF Symbols so it works on everyone else's machine.

```
struct GridPaddingView: View {
    
    let dataArray: [Datum] = [
        Datum(name: "square", image: "square.and.arrow.up.trianglebadge.exclamationmark", price: "$1.00"),
        Datum(name: "trash", image: "trash.slash.fill", price: "$1.00"),
        Datum(name: "folder", image: "folder.badge.minus", price: "$1.00"),
        Datum(name: "external drive", image: "externaldrive.fill.badge.minus", price: "$1.00"),
        Datum(name: "doc", image: "doc.fill.badge.plus", price: "$1.00"),
        Datum(name: "calendar", image: "calendar.day.timeline.leading", price: "$1.00")
    ]
    
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(180), spacing: 10), count: 2)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns)  {
                    ForEach(dataArray) { item in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Image(systemName: item.image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .frame(height: 140)
                                HStack {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text(item.name)
                                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                        Text(item.price)
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                    Button(action: {}) {
                                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                                    }
                                    .padding(10)
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(5)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            HStack() {
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {}) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "cart")
                                        Text("В Корзину")
                                            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.blue)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                        .frame(height: 300)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Datum: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let price: String
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My design should look like this https://imgur.com/a/rQ1Qw86 I tried your code and added like button next to first button but it's really no more space. How can I solve this problem?